# Twitter Ruby Random Twitter ID

Tags: ruby, twitter

I'm trying to randomly generate a twitter id and then follow that id if it meets the criteria. The problem is that when random_numbers doesn't actually exist it runs into error, I tried but i think i failed at trying to loop it until it finds one so is there a way to make random_number keep looping if that number doesn't link to a twitter id?

```
SET_VALUE = 0

random_number = rand(100000...100000000)
puts "#{random_number}"

random_user = @client.user(random_number)

puts "#{random_user}"
  while random_user == nil
    random_number = rand(100000...100000000)
    random_user = @client.user(random_number)
  end


num_followers = random_user.followers_count
@client.follow(random_user) if num_followers > SET_VALUE

puts "You have just followed #{random_user.screen_name}"
```

Comment: Its hard to generate twitter id's with random number, Why you trying this ?

Comment: I wanted to generate a random twitter account and the simplest way i thought was using twitter id since it was integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the simple way to solve it in your case is to ignore the error and continue. You can do this using

```
rescue nil
```

on the end of the line that is causing the error. In your case if doesn't matter if it causes an error as you are guessing at twitter ids.

I assume this is the line that is throwing the error:

```
random_user = @client.user(random_number)
```

so you can rescue it like so:

```
random_user = @client.user(random_number) rescue nil
```

You can read more here: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html